# XSL: chop off string at arbitrary place

Tags: pdf, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using XSL to get an XML styled. The xsl defines a table with two columns. Thanks to Kevin Brown, the following code works fine to chop off at a word boundary, but what I need is to chop off at an arbitrary place.

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" height="15pt"><fo:block>this is a very, very, very long text here</fo:block></fo:block-container>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you generate this from XML and XSL, you would normally create a template when outputting that particular content and place &#8203; entities (the zero-width breaking space character). So however you do it, make the content like this (this says "very long word" with that entity between the letters:

v&#8203;e&#8203;r&#8203;y l&#8203;o&#8203;n&#8203;g w&#8203;o&#8203;r&#8203;d

So in your example (I only put them near the break so you can see):

```
<fo:table-cell border="1pt solid silver">
                            <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" height="15pt"><fo:block>this is a very, very, very l&#8203;o&#8203;n&#8203;g t&#8203;e&#8203;x&#8203;t here</fo:block></fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
```

You would get this now ( it breaks at "o" in "long"):

[image]

A very interesting effect if you are so inclined is to set "text-align" as "justify" on that fo:block which will actually make all things align if at the end of the block you inserted an fo:leader of sufficient length to fill the cell. NOTE: This does not work in Apache FOP, it does in RenderX XEP.

Like:

```
<fo:table-cell border="1pt solid silver">
    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" height="15pt"><fo:block text-align="justify">this is a<fo:leader leader-length.minimum="3in"/></fo:block></fo:block-container>
</fo:table-cell>
```

If you did that, you would get this:

[image]